# How to select sum when left joined column does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select("a.*, SUM(b.amount) as total");
$this->db->join('table2 b', 'a.b_PID = b.PID', 'LEFT');
$this->db->from(table1 a');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

In my query above, I am left joining table b to table on b_PID, however not all records in table a have record in table b, therefore if I select SUM the amount in table b as above, record thas has no data in table b is not returned. How do i select sum b.amount and return amount as 0 if there is no record in table b ? For some reasons, I cannot use group_by.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You appear to be missing a GROUP BY clause

Comment: I stated in my question clearly that I cannot use group_by

Comment: I suggest you address those 'reasons' - or otherwise handle the arithmetic in application code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **COALESCE**

```
  SELECT d.*
  , IFNULL(SUM(a.total),0) AS total
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM table2 b) d
  LEFT JOIN table1 a
  a.b_PID = b.PID
```

Comment: Yes I did try using coalesce but it still does not return the row that does not has data in table b

Answer (score 1):

$this->db->select("a.*, SUM(CASE WHEN b.amount IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE o END) as total");